# Java Array of unique randomly generated integers

Tags: java, arrays

```
public static int[] uniqueRandomElements (int size) {

    int[] a = new int[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        a[i] = (int)(Math.random()*10);

        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (a[i] == a[j]) {
                a[j] = (int)(Math.random()*10);
            }
        }   
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(a[i]+" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    return a;
}
```

I have a method above which should generate an array of random elements that the user specifies. The randomly generated integers should be between 0 and 10 inclusive. I am able to generate random integers but the problem I have is checking for uniqueness. My attempt to check for uniqueness is in my code above but the array still contains duplicates of integers. What am I doing wrong and could someone give me a hint?

Comment: What happens when `size > 10`? How can you generate unique numbers for each index?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    a[i] = (int)(Math.random()*10);

    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        if (a[i] == a[j]) {
            a[j] = (int)(Math.random()*10); //What's this! Another random number!
        }
    }   
}
```

You do find the duplicate values. However, you replace it with another random number that may be a duplicate. Instead, try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    a[i] = (int)(Math.random()*10);//note, this generates numbers from [0,9]

    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        if (a[i] == a[j]) {
            i--; //if a[i] is a duplicate of a[j], then run the outer loop on i again
            break;
        }
    }  
}
```

However, this method is inefficient. I recommend making a list of numbers, then randomizing it:

```
ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>(11);
for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++){ //to generate from 0-10 inclusive. 
                               //For 0-9 inclusive, remove the = on the <=
    a.add(i);
}
Collections.shuffle(a);
a = a.sublist(0,4);
//turn into array
```

Or you could do this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(11);
for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
    list.add(i);
}
int[] a = new int[size];
for (int count = 0; count < size; count++){
    a[count] = list.remove((int)(Math.random() * list.size()));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It might work out faster to start with a **sequential array** and **shuffle** it. Then they will all be **unique by definition**.

Take a look at [Random shuffling of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519736/random-shuffling-of-an-array), and at the Collections.shuffle function.

```
int [] arr = [1,2,3,.....(size)]; //this is pseudo code

Collections.shuffle(arr);// you probably need to convert it to list first
```

Comment: Probably need? You definitely need to convert to a list.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a duplicate you only regenerate the corresponding number once. But it might create another duplicate. You duplicate checking code should be enclosed in a loop:

```
while (true) {
    boolean need_to_break = true;
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        if (a[i] == a[j]) {
            need_to_break = false; // we might get another conflict
            a[j] = (int)(Math.random()*10);
        }
    }
    if (need_to_break) break;
}
```

But make sure that `size` is less than `10`, otherwise you will get an infinite loop.

**Edit**: while the above method solves the problem, it is not efficient and should not be used for large sized arrays. Also, this doesn't have a guaranteed upper bound on the number of iterations needed to finish.

A better solution (which unfortunately only solves second point) might be to generate a sequence of the distinct numbers you want to generate (the `10` numbers), randomly permute this sequence and then select only the first `size` elements of that sequence and copy them to your array. You'll trade some space for a guarantee on the time bounds.

```
int max_number = 10;
int[] all_numbers = new int[max_number];
for (int i = 0; i < max_number; i++)
    all_numbers[i] = i;

/* randomly permute the sequence */
for (int i = max_number - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    int j = (int)(Math.random() * i); /* pick a random number up to i */

    /* interchange the last element with the picked-up index */
    int tmp = all_numbers[j];
    all_numbers[j] = a[i];
    all_numbers[i] = tmp;
}

/* get the a array */
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    a[i] = all_numbers[i];
```

Or, you can create an `ArrayList` with the same numbers and instead of the middle loop you can call `Collections.shuffle()` on it. Then you'd still need the third loop to get elements into `a`.

Comment: I appreciate your answer but I haven't had enough experience with Java to understand your answer.

Comment: Ummm, is there a Java compiler that lets you use `break` as a variable name?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't code in Java for several years and I forgot that :)

Comment: @MihaiMaruseac There aren't many languages that let you use variable names that are the same as keyword names.  I'd think `if (break) break;` should have been a warning flag, in any language ... :)

Comment: Haskell programmer here :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just don't want to pay for the added overhead to ArrayList, you can just use an array and use [Knuth shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle):

```
public Integer[] generateUnsortedIntegerArray(int numElements){
    // Generate an array of integers
    Integer[] randomInts = new Integer[numElements];
    for(int i = 0; i < numElements; ++i){
        randomInts[i] = i;
    }
    // Do the Knuth shuffle
    for(int i = 0; i < numElements; ++i){
        int randomIndex = (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        Integer temp = randomInts[i];
        randomInts[i] = randomInts[randomIndex];
        randomInts[randomIndex] = temp;
    }
    return randomInts;
}
```

The above code produces numElements consecutive integers, without duplication in a uniformly random shuffled order.

Answer (score 0):

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 class Unique
{
public static void main(String[]args)
{
    int i,j;
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] a=new int[10];
    System.out.println("Here's a unique no.!!!!!!");
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        a[i]=(int)(Math.random()*10);
        for(j=0;j<i;j++)
        {
            if(a[i]==a[j])
            {
                i--;

            }
        }   
    }
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        System.out.print(a[i]);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Input your size and get list of random unique numbers using Collections.

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> noRepeatShuffleList(int size) {
    ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        arr.add(i);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(arr);
    return arr;
}
```

Elaborating Karthik's answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] a = new int[20];

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    a[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 20);

    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        if (a[i] == a[j]) {
            a[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 20); //What's this! Another random number!
            i--;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int[] a = new int [size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    {
        a[i] = (int)(Math.random()*16); //numbers from 0-15
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) 
        {
            //Instead of the if, while verifies that all the elements are different with the help of j=0
            while (a[i] == a[j])
            {
                a[i] = (int)(Math.random()*16); //numbers from 0-15
                j=0;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(i + ".   " + a[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation as to how this solves the problem, or how this differs from the existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/23880125)

Answer (score 0):

```
//Initialize array with 9 elements
int [] myArr = new int [9];
//Creating new ArrayList of size 9
//and fill it with number from 1 to 9
ArrayList<Integer> myArrayList = new ArrayList<>(9);
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        myArrayList.add(i + 1);
        }
//Using Collections, I shuffle my arrayList
Collections.shuffle(myArrayList);
//With for loop and method get() of ArrayList
//I fill my array
for(int i = 0; i < myArrayList.size(); i++){
    myArr[i] = myArrayList.get(i);
    }

//printing out my array
for(int i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++){
    System.out.print(myArr[i] + " ");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution:

```java
public static int[] uniqueRandomElements(int size) {
    List<Integer> numbers = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, size).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    return Collections.shuffle(numbers);
}
```