# Jquery for loop assigning a random value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a student and very new to coding, I'll try my best to explain the issue i'm having. So I have an array which I want to show up as buttons on my page using jquery. Each button needs to be assigned a random value between 1 and 12. I have a for loop going through the buttons assigning a random value. I got that to work. My problem however, is that I don't want any of the buttons to contain the same value. So if the first button generates a random value of "2" I don't want any of the last 3 buttons to contain a value of "2". Here is my code so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Create random number between 19 and 120
    var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (120 - 19 + 1) + 19);
    console.log(number);
    //show random number to user

    var randomNumberField = $("#randomNumber");
    randomNumberField.text(number);

    //Create crystals/buttons
    var Crystals = [1, 2, 3, 4];


    for (var i = 0; i < Crystals.length; i++) {
        var crystalNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (12 - 1 + 1) + 1);
        console.log(crystalNumber);

        if ($("crystalNumber") === $("Crystals")) {
            crystalNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (12 - 1 + 1) + 1);
        };

        else(var i = 0; i < Crystals.length; i++)

        var crystalImage = $("<img>");


    }



}); // end of script
```

Comment: What do you mean by this line if ($("crystalNumber") === $("Crystals")) ?

Comment: Try look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039025/java-array-of-unique-randomly-generated-integers

Comment: You say that attributing random numbers is working... Can you share the HTML?

Comment: @Martin: The answer you suggest is Java... Java is to JavaScript what a car is to a carpet. ;)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette My b, this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380019/generate-unique-random-numbers-between-1-and-100

Comment: You choose a random item from the array and remove it from the array. Repeat.

Comment: @Martin: It was clearly asked for a jQuery solution.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I used console.log to show the random values it was generating, and that's how I discovered sometimes some of the numbers would have the same value.

Comment: Okay... And did you try to use my solution?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your crystals... I assumed 4 buttons for this example.

To make sure a random number isn't used more than once, first you have to use an array to store the used ones.

Then each time you try to obtain a new one, run a [`while`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while) loop until the number produced **is not** in the already used ones array.

The test to know if in the array or not is done using [`.$.inArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  var buttons = $(".randNumber");
  var randNumbers = [];

  buttons.each(function(index){
    number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 12) + 1);
    
    while( $.inArray(number,randNumbers) != -1 ){
      number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 12) + 1);
    }
    
    randNumbers.push(number);
    buttons.eq(index).html(number);
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="randNumber"></button>
<button class="randNumber"></button>
<button class="randNumber"></button>
<button class="randNumber"></button>
```

Comment: Worth noting that you are able to get duplicate values of your buttons in the current example: https://gyazo.com/e83d0d76cb3d2f389c38a38648da2bae

Comment: Thanks @Martin. I fixed it... It strangely took me a lot time to remember that `$.inArray()` is not returning a boolean, but an array index... Which is `-1` when not found. ;)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I'm sorry, I'm also new to stackoverflow you said you fixed it? Does that mean the code above has been edited? or will it still sometimes generate the same values? I think this will help and I think I understand what your code is doing. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Yes, It has been edited. the condition of the `while` loop was wrong. It's now ok.