# Generating a 1d random int array fixed range containing no duplicates

Tags: java, arrays

```
public static int[] generatePicks(int size, int lowValue, int highValue, long seed) {
    Random rand = new Random(seed);
    int[] arr = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = rand.nextInt((highValue - lowValue) + 1) + lowValue;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
                arr[i] = rand.nextInt((highValue - lowValue) + 1) + lowValue;
            }
        }
    }    
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    return arr;   
}
```

How can i ensure that the newly created random int doesn't match any pre-existing? I don't want to use any methods not pertaining to one-dimensional arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Try contains:

```
    public static int[] generatePicks(int size, int lowValue, int highValue, long seed) {
    Random rand = new Random(seed);
    int[] arr = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = getRandom(arr, rand, lowValue, highValue);
    }
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    return arr;
}

private static int getRandom(int[] arr, Random rand, int lowValue, int highValue) {
    int nextInt = rand.nextInt((highValue - lowValue) + 1) + lowValue;
    if (Arrays.asList(arr).contains(nextInt)) {
        return getRandom(arr, rand, lowValue, highValue);
    }
    return nextInt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you only want to work with array's and no other data type so this is an array only solution although the code could probably be made more efficient if other types and methods was allowed.

This code also handles the situation where the `size` parameter is larger than the difference between `highValue` and `lowValue` to avoid an infinite loop. It handles the situation by changing the size used but maybe a better option would be to throw an exception.

```
public static int[] generatePicks(int size, int lowValue, int highValue, long seed) {
    Random rand = new Random(seed);

    int usedSize = size > highValue - lowValue ? highValue - lowValue : size;
    int[] arr = new int[usedSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < usedSize; i++) {
        arr[i] = rand.nextInt((highValue - lowValue) + 1) + lowValue;

        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
                i--; 
                break;
            }
        } 
    } 
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    return arr;   
}
```

The inner loop used for checking for duplicates was taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20039071/9223839)

Answer (score 0):

Here are three approachs:

1)

Your own approach only with a modified inner loop that goes through all previous random numbers from `0 to i-1` and checks for duplicates. If a duplicate is found just force a generation of a new random number by decrementing the index of the outer loop `--i`

```
public static int[] generatePicks3(int size, int lowValue, int highValue, long seed) {
    Random rand = new Random(seed);
    int[] arr = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = rand.nextInt((highValue - lowValue) + 1) + lowValue;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (arr[j] == arr[i]) {
                --i;
            }
        }
    }    
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    return arr;   
}
```

2)

Using `IntStream(lowValue, highValue+1)` and `Collections.shuffle(List<?>, rand)`

Generate all numbers between `lowValue` and `highValue` collect them to list, shuffle the list and get the first `n` elements, where `n = size`

```
public static int[] generatePicks2(int size, int lowValue, int highValue, long seed) {
    Random rand = new Random(seed);
    List<Integer> list = IntStream.range(lowValue, highValue+1).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    Collections.shuffle(list, rand);
    return list.stream().limit(size).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sorted().toArray();
}
```

3)

The simplest and shortest way using `Random.ints()`: generate an infinite stream of random numbers between `lowValue` and `highValue` make them unique by applying `distinct()` and limit the stream to the desiered `size`.

```
public static int[] generatePicks(int size, int lowValue, int highValue, long seed) {
    Random rand = new Random(seed);
    return rand.ints(lowValue, highValue).distinct().limit(size).sorted().toArray();
}
```